# cual es la diferencia entre un getElementsByTagNameNs() y un getElementsByTagName()

Tags: java, xml, bonita

buenos días estoy consumiendo un web service a través de bonitasoft  con el editor groovy pero no he  tenido éxito, ya que al momento de  manejar el xml no puedo obtener toda la información de este mismo, creo que el inconveniente es de la forma que estoy utilizando el  getElementsByTagName pero al momento de buscar información encontré también el  getElementsByTagNameNs  que tiene unos parámetros muy parecidos pero no me queda muy clara la diferencia entre los 2 , ya que creo al saber  como utilizar mejor el tag podre consumir mi web service de manera adecuada, por que al momento de realizar el mapeo me brinda toda la información en un solo String  y quiere que me quede separada como esta en el xml 
anexo mi código cualquier ayuda o aclaración estaré agradecido.

```js
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import java.lang.Exception;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import java.lang.StackTraceElement;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.xml.DomDriver;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.Converter;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.HierarchicalStreamReader;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.HierarchicalStreamWriter;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.MarshallingContext;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.UnmarshallingContext;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.basic.AbstractSingleValueConverter;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;

String ejemplo = "";
String aux = "";
boolean bandera ;


// Clean response xml document
responseDocumentBody.normalizeDocument();
// Get result node
NodeList resultList = responseDocumentBody.getElementsByTagName("*");
Element resultElement = (Element) resultList.item(0);
String weatherDataAsXML = resultElement.getTextContent();
aux  = aux +  (Element) resultList.item(0);
XStream xstream = new XStream();
String xml = xstream.toXML(aux);

// Check for empty result
if ("Data Not Found".equalsIgnoreCase(weatherDataAsXML))
 return null;

// Parse embedded XML of result
DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
InputSource inputSource = new InputSource();
inputSource.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(aux));
 try{ejemplo = ejemplo +"|-|";
 XPath xpath=XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
 Document weatherDataDocument=DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(inputSource);


 Node nodePrincipal=(Node)xpath.evaluate("/MortgageResults/MonthlyPrincipalAndInterest",weatherDataDocument,XPathConstants.NODE);
 ejemplo = ejemplo +"|error?|";
 
 if (null == nodePrincipal)
  bandera = true;
 
  ejemplo = ejemplo +"|lo hace?|";
 if (bandera ==true)
 {
  ejemplo = ejemplo + " si hay algo ";
 }else {
  ejemplo = ejemplo +"no hay nadad";
 }
 
 NodeList childNodes = weatherNode.getChildNodes();
 
 
 ejemplo = ejemplo +"|=)|";
 NodeList ejemploNodo = weatherDataDocument.getDocumentElement();
 ejemplo = ejemplo +"|=)|";
 ejemplo = ejemplo +  nodeToString(ejemploNodo.getTextContent().toUpperCase());
 //ejemplo = ejemplo +"|=)|";
 //String principal = nodeToString(nodePrincipal.getDocumentElement());//pass in the root
 //String principal=nodePrincipal.getTextContent().toUpperCase();
 ejemplo = ejemplo +"|=)|";
 Node nodeTax=(Node)xpath.evaluate("/MortgageResults/MonthlyTax",weatherDataDocument,XPathConstants.NODE);
 String tax=nodeTax.getTextContent().toUpperCase();
 ejemplo = ejemplo +"|-|";
 
 
 //Document weatherDataDocument = documentBuilder.parse(inputSource);
 //Node weatherNode = (Node) xPath.compile(expression).evaluate(inputSource, XPathConstants.NODE);
 ejemplo = ejemplo +"|-|";
 
 // Save weather data
 Map<String,String> data = new HashMap<String,String>();
 ejemplo = ejemplo +"|-|";
 NodeList childNodes = weatherNode.getChildNodes();
 ejemplo = ejemplo +"|y|";
 for (int i=0; i<childNodes.getLength(); i++)
 {

  Node node = childNodes.item(i);
 
  if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE)
  {
    ejemplo = ejemplo +childNodes.item(i).getNodeName() + " : " +weatherNode.getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
  }
 }
  for (int i=0; i<childNodes.getLength(); i++)
 {

  Node node = childNodes.item(i);
  
 
  if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE)
  {
   String key = childNodes.item(i).getNodeName()
   
   String value = node.getTextContent();// necesito  obtener el valor de los nodos hijos
   ejemplo = ejemplo + "key ->"+key + " value ->"+value ;
   data.put(key, value);
   
   Iterator it = data.entrySet().iterator();
   while (it.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry e = (Map.Entry)it.next();
    ejemplo = ejemplo+" "+ e.getKey() + " " + e.getValue();
   }
   
  }
 }
}catch(Exception ex){
  StackTraceElement[] stackTraceElement =ex.getStackTraceElement(0);
   int n = stackTraceElement.length;
  ejemplo = ejemplo +"---oooo---";
  for (int i = 0 ;i<n;i++ )
  {
  ejemplo = ejemplo+ " "+stackTraceElement[i].getLineNumber()+">>"+stackTraceElement[i].getMethodName();
  }
 }
return ejemplo;
```

```html
<MortgageResults xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.webserviceX.NET/">
<MonthlyPrincipalAndInterest>0.083785411555805267</MonthlyPrincipalAndInterest>
<MonthlyTax>0.91666666666666663</MonthlyTax>
<MonthlyInsurance>0.083333333333333329</MonthlyInsurance>
<TotalPayment>1.0837854115558052</TotalPayment>
</MortgageResults>
```

gracias de antemano por su atención

Comment: Ten en cuenta que DocumentBuilderFactory tiene un método setNamespaceAware, si trabajas con XML documentos con "namespaces" y quieres utilizar getElementsByTagNameNS tienes que aplicar setNamespaceAware(true) para DocumentBuilderFactory.

Comment: @MartinHonnen gracias martin por la información  al momento realizar este procedimiento tendré en cuenta  para aplicarlo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getElementsByTagName(ParametroTag)` te devuelve todos los tagname que coinciden con el string `ParametroTag`.

`getElementsByTagNameNs(ParametroNameSpace, ParametroTag)` te devuelve todos los tagname que coinciden con el string `ParametroTag` siempre que cumplan la condición de estar dentro del namespace especificado en el string `ParametroNameSpace`.

Ejemplo:

```
//obtenemos las celdas de una tabla en un documento XHTML.
var tabla = document.getElementById("tabla-principal");
var celdas = tabla.getElementsByTagNameNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml", "td");
```

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta me aclaro mucho la duda que tenia